# Delete button in a table using Javascript doesn't work. I cannot get the value of the edit button. I have this code:

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, delete-row

```
$(".btn-add-dependent").click(function () {
  var checked = $("#disability").is(':checked') ? "checked='checked'" : "";
  $("#dependents-info tbody").append(
     "<tr><td>" + $("#first-name").val() + "</td><td>" 
     + $("#middle-name").val() + "</td><td>" 
     + $("#last-name").val() + "</td><td>" 
     + $("#dependents-birthday").val() 
     + "</td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'" + checked 
     + "</td><td><button><span class='btn-edit-dependent glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button><button><span class='btn-delete-dep glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></td></tr>");
  });

  // delete dependent button
  $('.btn-delete-dep').click(function () {
     alert('m;lasfdj;adsdas');
  });
```

Comment: Please, improve your question: make the title a title. Explain what your code is expected to do, and what is failing. Please, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: replace to `$('.btn-add-dependent').on("click", ".btn-delete-dep",function () {...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dependents-info').on('click','.btn-delete-dep',function () {
     alert('m;lasfdj;adsdas');
});
```